# Segmentation Fault in double pointer assignment

Tags: c

I have declared double pointer like this

```
UInt8  **contentKeyCtx;
```

This variable is sent as argument to a function
Inside the function there is local variable

```
 UInt8    *localckc     = NULL;
 localckc = calloc(1, localckcSize);
```

Then there is some array of values assigned to `localckc`

When i try to do this

```
 *contentKeyCtx = localckc;
```

I got Segmentation Fault

What i am doing wrong? 
Main function

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    OSStatus result; // SInt32


    UInt8  *inBuff, *outBuff;
    UInt32 inBuffSize, outBuffSize;
    UInt8  **contentKeyCtx = calloc(1, sizeof(UInt8**));
    UInt32  *contentKeyCtxSize;
    FILE   *fp;


    const UInt8 *assetId = {0x1b, 0xf7, 0xf5, 0x3f, 0x5d, 0x5d, 0x5a, 0x1f};// what is this?



    inBuff=calloc(1,INBUFFSIZE);
    outBuff=calloc(1,OUTBUFFSIZE);


    inBuffSize = fread(inBuff, sizeof(UInt8), INBUFFSIZE, fp);

    fclose(fp);


    // IK we have some data. Now what?
    result = SKDServerGenCKC(inBuff, inBuffSize, assetId, contentKeyCtx, contentKeyCtxSize);


    free(inBuff);
    free(outBuff);
    printf("Result is  %d\n", result );
    return 0;
}
```

Actual function implementation

```
    OSStatus SKDServerGenCKC(
        const UInt8   *serverPlaybackCtx,
        UInt32         serverPlaybackCtxSize,
        const UInt8   *assetId,
        UInt8        **contentKeyCtx,
        UInt32        *contentKeyCtxSize)
{

    UInt8    *localckc     = NULL;
    UInt32    localckcSize = 0;
    PS_RequireAction(ckcContainer      != NULL, return kDRMSKDServerParamErr;)
    PS_RequireAction(contentKeyCtx     != NULL, return kDRMSKDServerParamErr;)
    PS_RequireAction(contentKeyCtxSize != NULL, return kDRMSKDServerParamErr;) 
    ...
     localckc = calloc(1, localckcSize);
     status = SKDServerWriteBytes(
                &ckcContainer->parser.currentOffset, PS_AES128_IV_SZ, 
                ckcContainer->aesKeyIV, localckcSize, localckc);


    ...
    *contentKeyCtx = localckc;


}
```

Comment: I think instead of `*contentKeyCtx = localckc;` you meant `contentKeyCtx = &localckc;`.

Comment: *The operator `*` can only be used when you have `Uint8 **` contentKeyCtx initialized*...

Comment: At the point where you are copying the 8 bytes of localckc to the address in contentKeyCtx, does contentKeyCtx have a value? But I'm confused by your question because it appears as though contentKeyCtx is declared in the caller and localckc is declared in the function. So, unless contentKeyCtx is a global variable, you won't be able to compile the code. If it is a global variable, then you really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: it is not global variable, it is passed as an argument to the function. static OSStatus SKDServerSerializeCKCContainer(
    SKDServerCKCContainerV1  *ckcContainer, 
    UInt8                       **contentKeyCtx,
    UInt32                      *contentKeyCtxSize)

Comment: How about editing your post to include the signature and the call to the function and the position of the assignment relative to the function?

Comment: To understand your high-level issue you show to few code. So any answer saying more that you may not de-reference an uninitialised pointer (as you seem to be doing here: `*contentKeyCtx = ...`)  would be just guessing.

Comment: I have added the function signature, let me know if you need more code added

Comment: "When I try to do this" Is that try inside the function or in the caller just before calling the function? Clarify that in your OP.

Comment: `*contentKeyCtx = localckc;` this is code in the function

Comment: You need to show the code that executes SKDServerGenCKC. It is the one that is responsible for setting the value that it's passing as contentKeyCtx.

Comment: @jeff6times7 `SKDServerGenCKC(inBuff, inBuffSize, assetId, contentKeyCtx, contentKeyCtxSize);` This is the code that executes the function

Comment: What function calls SKDServerGenCKC? Show that in its entirety.

Comment: @jeff6times7 added the whole main function, This is code from apple Fairplay streaming and i don't know how to initialize `contentKeyCtx ` properly so this code can work

Comment: As soon as you added `main`, John answered before I could have. Of course, he got it right. This entire comment conversation would have been unnecessary had you posted an [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm not wanting you to interpret this as being mean-spirited. On the contrary, I want to be a good helper and encourage you to be more diligent in posting good questions, those that are more likely to get upvoted. Have a blessed day.

Comment: @jeff6times7 of course you are right, i saw what you mean when i saw the answer. Will have this in mind for future questions, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function implementation you have now presented differs in an important way from your original description of the problem.  It is now clear that the pointer involved, `contentKeyCtx`, is a function parameter, not a local or file-scope variable, and the code shows that it is being used to convey a pointer computed by the function back to the function's caller.

In this case, the corresponding actual argument to the function call should be the address of an appropriately-typed variable in which the function will store the generated pointer value, like so:

```
UInt8        *contentKeyCtx;
UInt32       contentKeyCtxSize = 0;
OSStatus     status;

status = SKDServerGenCKC(..., &contentKeyCtx, &contentKeyCtxSize);
```

Similar applies to the last argument, as shown; it apparently is used to return the size of the space to which the returned pointer points.

Answer (score 1):

`contentKeyCtx`

Is not initialized, it's pointing to nothing.

Comment: How can i initialize it so the code can work properly?

Comment: You want to say `contentKeyCtx` were not initialised. `**contentKeyCtx` is something different.

Comment: `UInt8  **contentKeyCtx = calloc(1, sizeof(Uint8*));`

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, I wanted to write `contentKeyCtx` but i wrote it with `**` instead.

Comment: Although allocating space would resolve the immediate problem, it is probably the wrong solution.

Answer (score 1):

> What i am doing wrong?

*There are two ways you can solve your problem:*

1. Initialize `contentKeyCtx`:

   ```
   // Use 'calloc()', if you want it to be zero by default...
   UInt8  **contentKeyCtx = malloc(1, sizeof(Uint8*));
   // Do something with it...
   ```

   **Or:** Re-allocate it:

   ```
   UInt8  **contentKeyCtx;
   contentKeyCtx = realloc(NULL, sizeof(Uint8*));
   // Do something with it...
   ```
2. Use the [*address-of*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) operator (a.k.a `&`):

   ```
   contentKeyCtx = &localckc;
   ```

Comment: I still get Segmentation Fault. I think i need to allocate *contentKeyCtx in order to work